# VAAPI usage monitoring

Tags: monitoring, load, vaapi

I have Intel Core-i7 8650U processor. I transcode video with ffmpeg. I take attempts to accelerate it. Now I use VAAPI codecs in ffmpeg (h264_vaapi) and vaapi rescaling (scale_vaapi) in filters. 
And when I use them my CPU load is not on maximum, but framerate doesn't insrease more. So I think that VAAPI's resources are over. **So I have to monitor the usage of Intel graphics hardware that is in my CPU. Is there any API or tool that could show usage of this hardware?** 
(It would be cool to know both tool(like **htop**) and opportunity to request it at moment from any script (like **ps aux**) or at least one of them).

For CPU         it's htop
For NVIDIA GPUs it's nvidia-smi
**For VAAPI       it's ...?**

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool for checking Intel iGPU usage: `intel_gpu_top`

You can install it in ubuntu via:

```
$ sudo apt-get install intel-gpu-tools
```

Or download it from official web page: https://www.x.org/archive/individual/app/intel-gpu-tools-1.22.tar.xz

After it is available in your OS, you just need to run it using sudo privileges and close it using Ctrl+C:

```
$ sudo intel_gpu_top
intel-gpu-top -   18/  17 MHz;   96% RC6;  0.03 Watts;       46 irqs/s

      IMC reads:   ------ (null)/s
     IMC writes:   ------ (null)/s

          ENGINE      BUSY                                                                                                        MI_SEMA MI_WAIT
     Render/3D/0    1.88% |█▉                                                                                                   |      0%      0%
       Blitter/0    0.00% |                                                                                                     |      0%      0%
         Video/0    0.00% |                                                                                                     |      0%      0%
  VideoEnhance/0    0.00% |                                                                                                     |      0%      0%
```